# How to index models in wagtail on azure search

Tags: python, django, azure, wagtail, azure-cognitive-search

I need to index my models on azure using the wagtail CMS platform. I have crud functionality written that hits the AZURE service, and can create indexes based on hard coded data.

```
def createIndex(request):
    endpoint = 'https://service-test.search.windows.net/'
    api_version = '2020-06-30'
    url = endpoint + "indexes?api-version=" + api_version

    index_schema = {
        "name": "hotels-test",  
        "fields": [
            {"name": "HotelId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": "true", "filterable": "true"},
            {"name": "HotelName", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "false", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "false"},
            {"name": "Description", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "false", "sortable": "false", "facetable": "false", "analyzer": "en.lucene"},
            {"name": "Description_fr", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "false", "sortable": "false", "facetable": "false", "analyzer": "fr.lucene"},
            {"name": "Category", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "Tags", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "false", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "ParkingIncluded", "type": "Edm.Boolean", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "LastRenovationDate", "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "Rating", "type": "Edm.Double", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "Address", "type": "Edm.ComplexType", 
                "fields": [
                    {"name": "StreetAddress", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": "false", "sortable": "false", "facetable": "false", "searchable": "true"},
                    {"name": "City", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
                    {"name": "StateProvince", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
                    {"name": "PostalCode", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
                    {"name": "Country", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'api-key': 'key*******'}

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=index_schema)
    index = response.json()

    return HttpResponse(response)
```

However, I have a bunch of folders, and each on has a model file. I need to somehow index the models, but I have no idea where to start with this? Can someone point me in the right directions?

Thank you

Comment: You need to create a unique index definition. Assuming the folders contain other type of data (customer rather than hotel for example), you'll need to create a new index to store that type of data. Imagine index as tables in a relational database.

Comment: How would I go about getting that onto Azure from my code base then? @ThiagoCustodio

Comment: you need to code something for that: read your data, push to azure cognitive search (using rest APIs)

Comment: Would you know of any tutorials/guides for this. I'm really struggling with using it in wagtail

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents

Answer (score 1):

In

https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/master/specification/search/data-plane/Azure.Search/preview/2020-06-30-Preview/examples/SearchServiceCreateIndex.json

you can find the request and response of the RestAPI.

By the way we have a SDK and some samples for this scenario.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/search/azure-search-documents/samples/sample_index_crud_operations.py#L41-L62

(I work in MS in the SDK team)